# Creating variables based on whether a column contains a particular string during groupby in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the below data which signifies how many times a person used different services :

```
account     site                        hitCount
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      3
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      1
243601      respframework.facebook.com  2
243601      respframework.facebook.com  1
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      6
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      2
243601      pie.prod.facebook.com       1
243601      profile.facebook.com        5
243601      respframework.facebook.com  4
243601      mediasearch.facebook.com    1
243601      pie.prod.facebook.com       2
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      1
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      1
243601      respframework.facebook.com  1
243601      profile.facebook.com        2
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      4
243601      collaborateext.facebook.com 1
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      1
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      2
243601      auth.svcs.facebook.com      4
243601      www.facebook.com            2
```

The sample data is for 1 customer. The original data has about 80k customers.

I am doing a group by per account to get a sum of the number of hits as below:

```
df_hits.groupby(level = 0)['hitCount'].sum().reset_index()
```

However, I also need to create 3 more variables as below:

```
account hitCount    profile_hit profile_hit_count   non_profile_hit_count
243601  47          1           2                   45
```

- profile_hit is a binary flag signifying if the site contains 'profile' or not.
- profile_hit_count is the number of times the account has hit site containing profile(profile.facebook.com) in the data.
- non_profile_hit_count is hitCOunt - profile_hit_count.

I am not sure how to create the other variables during group by.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: for profile_hit_count you need to group by the column site also and you will get multiple rows for the same account number..Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: "Creating several variables during groupby in pandas" is the title of a question that is not going to help anyone besides you. Please re-think your question, break it down into simpler parts, and try again.

Comment: @coldspeed what is the best way to communicate with you? ur email id or linkedin id?

Comment: @coldspeed. Thank you. I have updated the title as per what I am looking to accomplish and tried to make it more generic, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#create new column for check string profile and cast to integers
df_hits =df_hits.assign(profile_hit_count=df_hits['site'].str.contains('profile').astype(int))
#aggregate `sum` twice - for profile_hit_count for count aocurencies
df = df_hits.groupby(level = 0).agg({'hitCount':'sum', 'profile_hit_count':'sum'})
#difference
df['non_profile_hit_count'] = df['hitCount'] - df['profile_hit_count']
#check if not 0 and cast to integer if necessary
df['profile_hit'] = df['profile_hit_count'].ne(0).astype(int)
print (df)
         hitCount  profile_hit_count  non_profile_hit_count  profile_hit
account                                                                 
243601         47                  2                     45            1
```